# Most efficient way to shift and merge the elements of a list in Python (2048)

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, python-3.x

I have a function that will essentially right align a list, but also merge two equal elements into one (the list will always have at least one element):

```
def shift(sequence):
    for i in range(len(sequence)-1):
        current_value = sequence[i]
        next_value = sequence[i+1]
        if next_value == 0:
            sequence[i], sequence[i+1] = 0, current_value
        elif current_value == next_value:
            sequence[i], sequence[i+1] = 0, current_value*2
    return sequence
```

Here's some example input and output:

```
>>> shift([0, 0, 1, 0])
[0, 0, 0, 1]
>>> shift([1, 1, 0, 0])
[0, 0, 0, 2]
>>> shift([2, 0, 1, 0])
[0, 0, 2, 1]
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this? And if this was being done to each row in a matrix, is there a more efficient way then doing:

```
matrix = [shift(row) for row in matrix]
```

Also, if I was to shift the matrix in the other three directions (apart from right), are there more efficient ways than these three:

```
#Left
matrix = [shift(row[::-1])[::-1] for row in matrix]

#Down
matrix = map(list, zip(*[shift(row) for row in map(list, zip(*matrix))]))

#Up
matrix = map(list, zip(*[shift(row[::-1])[::-1] for row in map(list, zip(*matrix))]))
```

If these shifting operations are being done repeatedly (as well as one of the values in the matrix being changed each time), are there any things I should keep track of to make it more efficient?

**EDIT**

My function does not always work:

```
>>> shift([1, 1, 1, 1])
[0, 2, 0, 2]
```

The output should be:

```
[0, 0, 2, 2]
```

More expected inputs and outputs:

```
[1, 1, 1]             --> [0, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 2] --> [0, 0, 1, 4, 3, 10, 2]
```

**EDIT 2**

It doesn't have to be shifting to the right, it can also be the other way.

Comment: Is this like the 1024 game?

Comment: @Cyber I have not heard of that so no.

Comment: Is the merging recursive? Or in other words, what is the result of `[1,1,1,1]`?

Comment: @NiklasB. `[1, 1, 1, 1] --> [0, 0, 2, 2]`. Actually that means my function doesn't work for that...

Comment: You should mention 2048 because theen everybody who knows the game can understand the question easier. Also you approach is already asymptotically optimal it seems

Comment: @NiklasB. Just looked up 2048. I have never heard of it before.

Comment: @NiklasB. My approach does not work for `[1, 1, 1, 1]`

Comment: @Scorpion_God It's hard to believe that this question is not part of an attempt to reimplement the game. There's nothing wrong with that by the way.

Comment: And please include the failing test case into the question

Comment: @NiklasB. I guess I just thought of something similar :)

Comment: @Scorpion_God Wait, why wouldn't `[1, 1, 1]` go to `[0, 1, 2]` or `[0, 2, 1]` (with the second one being more likely)?

Comment: @KirkStrauser sorry, edited again. It's shifting to the right, but starts from the rightmost pair, not the leftmost.

Answer (score 1):

Whether this is more efficient is up to `timeit`:

```
def streaming_sum(sequence):
    values = reversed(sequence)
    last = next(values)
    for value in values:
        if value == last:
            yield last + value
            last = 0
        else:
            yield last
            last = value
    yield last


def shift(sequence):
    length = len(sequence)
    reduced = list(reversed(filter(None, streaming_sum(sequence))))
    return [0] * (length - len(reduced)) + reduced


for sequence, expected in [
    ([0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]),
    ([1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2]),
    ([2, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 2, 1]),
    ([1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 2, 2]),
    ([1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2]),
    ([1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 2], [0, 0, 1, 4, 3, 10, 2]),
]:
    actual = shift(sequence)
    assert actual == expected, (actual, expected)
```

Comment: This causes an error: `TypeError: object of type 'filter' has no len()`

Comment: @Scorpion_God That's because `filter` returns different objects in Python 2 vs. Python 3 (list vs generator)

Comment: This will make `[1,1,1]` -> `[3]`. Agreed that the question is underspecified though.

Comment: This causes another error: `TypeError: argument to reversed() must be a sequence`

Comment: Ahh, you're using Python 3. Wrap `filter()` in `list()`.

Comment: This actually isn't very efficient. Also, wrapping the filter in a list, then a reversed, and then a list again seems to be very detrimental to performance. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my current solution. It is faster than Kirk Strauser's solution by about 60%.

```
def shift(self, sequence, right=False):
    if right:
        sequence = sequence[::-1]
    values = []
    empty = 0
    for n in sequence:
        if values and n == values[-1]:
            values[-1] = 2*n
            empty += 1
        elif n:
            values.append(n)
        else:
            empty += 1
    values += [0]*empty
    if right:
        values = values[::-1]
    return values
```

My more efficient one:

```
def shift2(length, sequence, right=False):
    if right:
        sequence = sequence[::-1]
    values = [0]*length
    full = 0
    for n in sequence:
        if full and n == values[full]:
            values[full] = 2*n
        elif n:
            values[full] = n
            full += 1
    if right:
        values = values[::-1]
    return values
```

Kirk's solution:

```
def streaming_sum(sequence):
    values = reversed(sequence)
    last = next(values)
    for value in values:
        if value == last:
            yield last + value
            last = 0
        else:
            yield last
            last = value
    yield last

def shift2(sequence):
    length = len(sequence)
    reduced = list(reversed(list(filter(None, streaming_sum(sequence)))))
    return [0] * (length - len(reduced)) + reduced
```

My improvement (40% speedup) on Kirk's function:

```
def shift3(sequence):
    length = len(sequence)
    reduced = [n for n in filter(None, streaming_sum(sequence))][::-1]
    return [0] * (length - len(reduced)) + reduced
```

---

Timing:

```
from timeit import Timer

tests = [[1000, 1000, 1000, 1000],
         [1000, 0, 0, 1000],
         [0, 1000],
         [1000, 1000, 0, 500, 0, 500, 1000, 0, 0, 100, 100, 100]]
t1, t2, t3 = 0, 0, 0

for test in tests:
    t1 += Timer(lambda: shift(test)).timeit()
    t2 += Timer(lambda: shift2(test)).timeit()
    t3 += Timer(lambda: shift3(test)).timeit()

>>> print(t1, t2, t3)
10.706327316242147 26.92895738572211 16.65189852514444
```

Timing of my one against my more efficient one against my more efficient one without the option for right-aligning instead of left-aligning:

```
10.502816527107633 8.503653343656246 8.15101370397509
```

Comment: I don't think your `shift` is correct though. It works from left to right and adds zeros to the right. E.g., `shift([1,1,1,2,2])` => `[2, 1, 4, 0, 0]` but it should be `[0,0,1,2,4]`.

Comment: It also has a side-effect on `sequence` which may not be desired.

Comment: @TooTone If you read my second edit, I said it can be the other way.